# JAWS is adding "Type and Text" at the end of information message

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

Below is the information section message which i am showing at the top of the page.JAWS is reading as

```
"You do not have privilege to edit record. Contact to your Customer Care. Type and Text."
```

I am not getting why it is adding "Type and Text" at the end. I want JAWS need to read only information message and do not need to add "Type and Text" message at the end. How to do it ? Below is my html code.

```
<div id="messagecontainer" role="region alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="all">
<h2 style="display: none">Messages</h2>
<section tabindex="0" id="infopanel" class="">
    <h2>Note</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>You do not have privilege to edit record. Contact to your Customer Care.</li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: It seems, it says "Type in text". I'll post an answer about how to turn it off, but I don't even imagine why it behaves as if there was an edit field, an `<input>` or a `<textarea>`.

Comment: I am also not getting it. Why it is saying "Type in Text", though there is no any input field.Please post your answer

Comment: Could you give a working example to test it with JAWS here or is it a private kind of area? Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @AndrePolykanine.  It's probably "type in text", as if it's on an input field. Given the brief code snippet in the question, I can't replicate the behavior with JAWS (2018) on IE11. I don't hear "type in text".  One questionable item is the `tabindex="0"` on the `<section>` element. That makes the section a tab stop but it is not an interactive element. If for some odd reason you had a `role="textbox"` on the section, then that might cause the problem, but that seems like a stretch. Also, how did you navigate to the section when you heard the message? Tab key or arrow keys?

Comment: when i came to page from menu, it is starting point of page.I am displaying information,error,warning messages at the top.Hence whenever JAWS left navigation menu, it starts reading this message. But when i am on same page i am using tab to read message.

Comment: During testing i removed role="region alert" from div and put role="alert" into ol tag. By doing this it works. Still not sure what is reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code.
Here it is working absolutely fine.
JAWS is not announcing any unwanted information such as: "Type and Text".
May be you are using the outdated version of JAWS.
Have you tried updating to the latest version?
Alternatively, please try to remove tabindex="0" as it is not needed and see that if it fixes your problem.